# JavaScript not work on chrome while its enabled in settings

Tags: javascript

This script is working only on firefox and in chrome it gives me that error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hidediv()
    {
        document.getElementById('divright').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('divleft').style.margin = "0 auto";
        document.getElementById('divleft').style.cssFloat = "none";
    } 

    function showdiv()
    {
        document.getElementById('divright').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('divleft').style.cssFloat = "left";
    } 
</script>

<div class="right_links">
    <nav class="reader_nav"><!-- html5 nav tag -->
        <span class="content" id="show4" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Content', 300);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" ></span>
        <span id="show5" class="prefrance" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Settings', 250);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"  ></span>
        <span id="show"  class="search" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Search', 210);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"></span>
        <span id="show2"  class="about" onmouseover="tooltip.show('About this book', 204);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"></span>
        <span id="show3"  class="help" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Help', 120);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" ></span>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other code? You are not calling `substring` as far as I can see. Where are your `hide` and `show` functions? What is `tooltip`?

Comment: no errors on my side, your question is asked poor as well

Comment: Some object of type String is undefined where it should not be. Use the debugging features of chrome to narrow down the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `tooltip.show` and `tooltip.hide` methods, my guess is that the error appears there since you don't use substring method anywhere.